# Going from main thread to background

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have method A that download images and it start it in background. Then it finished, it runs completion block.
I run method A and I in his completion block. I want to know - now I am in main or in background thread?

Comment: Post the relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: Have you bothered to actually try and attempt this yourself?

Comment: please improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably still in a background thread.  As was mentioned you can check if you're in the background using

```
[NSThread isMainThread]
```

If you want to switch to the main thread you can use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // do some things here in the main queue
    // for example: update UI controls, etc.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
[NSThread isMainThread];
```